# tab.current is null, why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client, use-ref

My problem is the following: As soon as I insert the code to include DB-data from Apollo client via UseQuery, it sets me tab.current to NULL. What am I doing wrong? I think I was already able to adjust the order of the React hooks correctly. Thank you.

```
function HomeHowItWorks() {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState(1);
  const [blockName, setBlockName] = useState("home");

  const tabs = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tabs.current);
  }, [tabs]);

  const heightFix = () => {
    if (tabs.current.children[tab - 1]) {
      tabs.current.style.height =
        tabs.current.children[tab - 1].offsetHeight + "px";
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    heightFix();
    //eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [tab]);
 
// Get DB-Content 
  const {
    data: homepageData,
    error: homepageError,
    loading: homepageLoading,
  } = useQuery(getPageHomepage, {
    variables: { blockname: blockName },
  });

  console.log(homepageData);
  if (homepageLoading) return "Loading header";
  if (homepageError) return `Oops there has been an error: ${homepageError}`;

  return (

...
```

React-Hook order should be okay.

I would like to embend the DB-data besides the tabState part.

Comment: Maybe don't disable `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` but instead heed it's warnings.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. If I tried it correctly, it has no effect.